# Hints of showing these two sets are diffeomorphic

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

Show that $A=\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2|r\geq 0,\,0\leq \theta\leq 3\pi/4\}$ is diffeomorphic to $B=\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2|r\geq 0,\,0\leq \theta\leq \pi/2\}$.

Indeed, I have an idea of showing this but it seems a bit complicated, so I'd like to see whether we have a clearer way of doing it.

Besides, may I ask how one can say that $B=\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2|r\geq 0,\,0\leq \theta\leq \pi/2\}$ is *non-diffeomorphic* to $C=\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2|r\geq 0,\,0\leq \theta\leq 3\pi/2\}$?

Comment: Have you considered $(r,\theta)\to (r,2\theta/3)$ as a possible diffeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, it is probably the usual way, but since $A$ and $B$ are not open, we should consider a smooth extension of the original bijective map; and I've made an extension but not perfectly sure of it. So I'd like to see whether someone have a nice smooth extension of this map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be the map that takes $(r,\theta)\rightarrow (r,\beta\theta)$ (suitable $\beta$) in polar coordinates and on a suitable 'wedge'. It is $C^\infty$ outside of the origin.
Let $h$ be a linear map, mapping (in cartesian coordinates)  $(1;0)$ to $(1;0)$ and (suitable $\theta_0$):
$$(\cos(\theta_0);\sin(\theta_0)) \mapsto (\cos(\beta\theta_0);\sin(\beta\theta_0))$$
Now let $\rho(r)$ be a $C^\infty$ function which is identical 1 for $0\leq r\leq \delta_0$ and  identically zero for $r\geq \delta_1>\delta_0$. Then (here writing $h$ in polar coordinates):
   $$f(r,\theta) = \rho(r) h(r,\theta) + (1-\rho(r)) g(r,\theta)$$
will do the job in the first case (but not the second).

I think you are right that the two other sets are not diffeomorphic as a linear map may not take a wedge of angle $>\pi$ to one of angle $<\pi$ (and vice versa). Quite interesting btw.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. May I ask why we cannot have a linear map take a wedge of angle bigger than pi to a wedge of angle smaller than pi? Do u mean the linear map, a smooth map instead? Since a diffeomorphism requires smoothness.

Comment: The two tangent vectors, say $v_1,v_2$ at the wedge point must map to two tangent vectors $u_1,u_2$ at the image wedge point. But if the angle of $v_1,v_2$ is smaller than pi and that of $u_1,u_2$ greater then the latter contains a wedge of angle pi (with vectors say $w_1=-w_2$)  and you can not map a non-trivial wedge to an angle $\pi$ since $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly dependent. (hope it is understandable?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but do we actually cannot have a tangent space at the wedge point i.e. the origin of those sets? Since you cannot form a vector space on those points coz you don't have an inverse vector?

Comment: I think your remark got 'gobled up' a bit? But I think you are saying the right thing: Looking in the inverse direction, If a wedge has angle greater than pi there must be linear segment through the wedge point inside the wedge. And by a diffeo this must be mapped to a curve with a tangent vector at the image wedge again sitting inside the wedge, so the image wedge must also have angle at least pi (and in fact strictly greater if the original angle was strictly greater).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I've thought about these kind of thing before, but now I'm clearer : )